# Run an application located in a directory from the PATH environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, command-line, environment-variables

I have an application located in a directory that is included in the PATH environment variable. So, if called from any directory with the DOS command line, the launch will succeed.

What is the easiest way to achieve the same thing in a .NET app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the CMD command with this syntax

```
Process.Start("CMD", "/C you_app_name.exe");
```

This is a static method and requires two arguments:

- the first one is the name of the program to start
- the second one are one or more arguments to pass to the starting program

Using CMD /C your_app_name.exe we start another instance of the command interpreter asking it to run you application and then exit.

Comment: If I have any arguments, can I just write Process.Start("CMD", "/C you_app_name.exe arg1 arg2") ?

Comment: Yes you could pass them after the filename of your app.

Comment: Actually, I could also write Process.Start("you_app_name.exe" ,"arg1 arg2"), I guess my environment variable was not set well